# Images flicker when table cell updated

Tags: ios, uitableview

In an iOS app, I have a table (UITableView) and within the table are cells that contain both an image and some text.

At times, I need to update the text in a cell without changing the image. These updates are triggered by events outside of the cell itself (for example, by a button being pushed in a different cell).

I have tried various ways to refresh the cell, including reloadRows and reloadSections, with or without animation. Regardless of what I do, the image sometimes blinks or flickers when the cell is updated. It doesn't happen every time, but it happens enough to be annoying.

I think that the blink happens in cases where the reload causes a new cell to be created rather than recycling the existing cell, but I don't really have control over that.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update UI properties in a cell *without* reloading the cell.

Ignoring the table view and cells for a moment, suppose we have a view with a `UILabel` and we want to change the text of the label on some button tap.

We don't do this:

```
let newLabel = UILabel()
newLabel.text = "New Text"
view.addSubview(newLabel)
// etc...
```

Instead, we simply do this:

```
someLabel.text = "New Text"
```

So, when we want to update the text of a label in a **cell**, we get a reference to the cell and update the label text directly.

Assuming we have a data structure like this:

```
struct SomeDataStruct {
    var imageName: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
}
```

and we have a cell similar to this:

```
class SomeCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and, we have data along these lines (filled with data):

```
var myData: [SomeDataStruct] = []
```

so our `cellForRowAt` looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SomeCustomCell
    c.imgView.image = UIImage(named: myData[indexPath.row].imageName)
    c.titleLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row].title
    return c
}
```

Now, if we want to update the label in the first cell (row Zero) *without* reloading the cell, we can do this:

```
let idxPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
if let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: idxPath) as? SomeCustomCell {
    // update the data, so the new label text will persist
    //  if/when the row is scrolled out of view
    myData[idxPath.row].title = "New Text"
    c.titleLabel.text = myData[idxPath.row].title
}
```

Comment: Personally I think you should avoid directly updating UI components of the custom cell class. The custom cell should provide data properties that can be set by the table view's data source. Let the custom cell's code update its own UI elements when the data properties are updated.

Comment: @HangarRash - true... although my answer was just to explain that we don't need to reload cells to update them. Ideally, the cell class would either have a var with `didSet` or a func to handle the UI update.